# Starting MySQL database server mysqld[fail]

Tags: mysql

Today I install MySQL on my Ubuntu 13.10, and it worked very well. But after I restart the computer, when I restart MySQL, it failed, and the log from /var/log/mysql is:

```
31216 22:40:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
131216 22:40:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
131216 22:40:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
131216 22:40:25 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131216 22:40:25 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131216 22:40:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131216 22:40:27 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 1609544
131216 22:40:27 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'
131216 22:40:27 [ERROR] Aborting

131216 22:40:27  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
131216 22:40:27  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1609544
131216 22:40:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

131216 22:40:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Could anyone help me to fix this issue, thanks!

Comment: please format your log output

Comment: Did you set this `default-character-set` in `my.cnf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fairly obvious from the log output.  `[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8'`

I think you're looking for [`character-set-server`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_character-set-server).

Comment: Right!!! I found it by myself a few minutes before,I delete that line in my.cnf, I add this line when I finished installing mysql, wrong congfiguration, thank you for you answer!

Comment: @user2593783 If this answer was helpful to you, you can mark it as the "accepted" answer by clicking the check-mark to the left of this post.